# Initialize Sitecore SiteInfo object

Tags: unit-testing, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a bit of a problem using the Sitecore `SiteInfo` object. This object contains details about a site, such as database name, site name and hostname, and can be used to create a `SiteContext` object. My problem is in setting the `RootPath`. The only [documentation](https://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.1.1/Sitecore.Web.SiteInfoMembers.html) I can find for this is for an older API version, and contains no details. As far as I can find, this is the way to create a `SiteInfo` and its `SiteContext`:

```cs
SiteInfo mySiteInfo = SiteInfo.Create(new StringDictionary { {"rootpath", "/sitecore/content"}, {"name", "mySite"}, {"foo", "bar"} });
SiteContext mySiteContext = new SiteContext(mySiteInfo);
```

Running this line gives no errors, but `mySiteInfo.RootPath` is still empty, even though `mySiteInfo.Name` has the value `mySite`. `{"foo", "bar"}` seems to be completely ignored, but that's no problem. Am I trying something Sitecore does not support?

Some more background: I'm trying to create a fake `SiteContext` using [Sitecore.FakeDB](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb), per the guide listed [here](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Sites), for use in my unit-tests. I need to set the `RootPath`, for testing my code.

Comment: Maybe it's just a problem with lowercase `p` letter, Try `rootPath` instead of `rootpath`.

Comment: I can not believe I didn't try that. OK, you got it! Can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties used during `SiteInfo` creation are case sensitive.

In your code there is `rootpath` all lowercase. You need to change it to `rootPath`.

You can find all the Sitecore built-in properties of site definition in the article [site Attribute Properties](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties.aspx).